# How to extract the output of a variable into another variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh

I have run one curl command to fetch the id of my applications and store it in a variable.
so when my echo command runs for this variable :-
 `echo appId : \$appId`
it gives output as :-
`appId : 6916404 6916405 6916406 6916407 6916408 6916409 6916446`

now I have to write a for loop for the above returned value of appId
so for that I am trying to write it as :-

```
for i in "\$appId";
        do
        Id=\${i%}
        echo Id: \$Id
curl command ..
done
```

but instead of getting the first value of i as "6916404" and second value as "6916405" and so on.. I am getting the complete set of values as output
`Id : 6916404 6916405 6916406 6916407 6916408 6916409 6916446`

Can someone please help me out here. I am trying to run this in Jenkins pipeline shell.

Comment: Is there any variable which I need to declare as an array?

Comment: A variable does not **output** anything. A process/program/function does. In your `echo` command,  only the literal string `Id: $Id`  gets printed, if you run this shell script as posted. Could it be that you are posting the Jenkins definition, and for this reason are escaping the `$` characters?

Comment: If you want to split the variable value in words, remove the quotes in the `for` statement like `for i in \$appId;`... (As mentioned in another comment, for a pure shell script the quoting of `$` is wrong as it would print the literal string instead of the variable value, e.g. `$appId` etc. I assume you have an environment where this is necessary.) Without seeing the code that assigns the value to `appId` and other code that may use the value, it is difficult to tell if an array would be more appropriate.